# ¿Es posible aplicar una recompensa a una pregunta propia?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Supongamos que existe una pregunta que hubiese realizado hace tiempo, pero no ha sido contestada a satisfacción. Entonces, quisiese aplicarle una recompensa para hacerle llamativa y promover que sea respuesta. ***¿Es esto posible?***

Answer (score 6):

## ¡Sí!

De la página de ayuda [¿Qué es una recompensa? ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Una recompensa es un premio especial de reputación concedido a una respuesta. La reputación se resta de la propia del usuario que la ofrece, y no es retornable. Si ves una pregunta que no ha obtenido una respuesta satisfactoria, una recompensa puede ayudar a atraer más atención y más respuestas. Toma entre +50 y +500 puntos de la reputación que has obtenido con tu propio esfuerzo, y [**asígnala a *cualquier* pregunta como recompensa**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). No necesitas ser el autor de una pregunta para iniciar una recompensa en ella.

Como detalle y para que veas que es algo no solo posible, sino incluso recomendado, existen medallas para ello:

- [Inversor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/45/investor): Primera recompensa que ofreces en *la pregunta de otra persona*.
- [Promotor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/46/promoter): Primera recompensa que ofreces en *tu propia pregunta*.

Comment: Me siento apenado por lo obvio de la pregunta, puesto se encuentra dentro de las instrucciones del centro de ayuda, lo que indica que me falto buscar un poco mas dentro de la guia del sitio.

Comment: @NederAlfonsoFandiñoAndrade no pasa nada, no siempre es obvio dónde está la documentación. Al menos no has tenido que ofrecer una recompensa para encontrarlo :)